# disable angular2 in-memory-web-api for production

Tags: angular

I'm using the angular2 `in-memory-web-api` for development. For the production environment I want to disable the in-memory-web-api and my real API to be used. Is there some way to disable the `InMemoryWebApiModule` for production?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have some kind of "switch", whether it be the Angular CLI `environment` to the the node ENV, you can just switch which `XHRBackend` should be used. The `in-memory-web-api` uses its own backend `InMemoryBackendService`. So you could do something like

```
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, XHRBackend, BrowserXhr,
         ResponseOptions,  XSRFStrategy } from '@angular/http';

import { InMemoryBackendService, InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

let environment = {
  production: true
};

export class MockData implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let cats = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Fluffy' }
    ];
    return { cats };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ HttpModule ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: XHRBackend,
      useFactory: (injector: Injector, browser: BrowserXhr,
                   xsrf: XSRFStrategy, options: ResponseOptions): any => {
        if (environment.production) {
          return new XHRBackend(browser, options, xsrf);
        } else {
          return new InMemoryBackendService(injector, new MockData(), {
            // the configuration object
          });
        }
      },
      deps: [ Injector, BrowserXhr, XSRFStrategy, ResponseOptions ]
    }
  ]
})
export class AppHttpModule {
}
```

Here, we're importing the `HttpModule`, then creating the `XHRBackend` dependency dynamically. In a development environment, it will use the backend service, which is actually what happens when we use the `InMemoryWebApiModule`. So instead of using that module, we just configure the backend service ourselves. And in a production environment, it just uses the same `XHRBackend`, that would normally be used.

Also notice the `environment`. This is just an example. This will probably not be used by you. Ideally, the environment should be something that is controlled on the command line. With Angular CLI, it actually does provide an `environment` variable located in `environment/environment`. The environment automatically gets switch by CLI in a production build.

If you're not using CLI, then you could probable use the node ENV or whatever way you plan the switch the production. The point is, the `environment` used above is just an example. Ideally this is not something that you want to have to manually change. You project should have some way to determine a production build, and that should be able to be accessed in your code.

Also with the above `AppHttpModule`, you no longer need to import the `HttpModule` into your `AppModule`, just import the `AppHttpModule`

Comment: This is a great example.  Really helping me simplify things. I am not following what the browser argument does though.

Comment: @Winnemucca These are all the dependencies required for the XHRBackend. You may not know what it is for, but it is what is required. I just looked at the source for XHRBackend, and saw that it requires this, so I added it as a dependency. Same for the ResponseOptions and the XSRFStrategy. I can't tell you exactly what the backend uses them for, but if you are curious, look at the source code for the backend. I didn't just make this up. The backend requires these things, whether we create it, or Angular does.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/http/src/backends

Comment: @Winnemucca but as [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45170805/2587435), you may not even need to create your own backend. I hadn't thought about that when I posted this answer. What will happen is that the HttpModule will already create the XHRBackend. But by importing the InMemoryWebApiModule _after_ the `HttpModule`, the `InMemoryBackendService` (which extends XHRBackend) will be used. If we remove the `InMemoryWebApiModule`, then the normal XHRBackend will be used. So the linked answer is probably the better way to go. Instead of dealing with backend, just deal with modules

Answer (score 8):

This simple approach works for me:

```js
const ENV = 'prod'; // your global ENV variable;
-----

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpModule,
    ENV !== 'prod' ? InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(DataMockService) : [],
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same way:

```
import { environment } from './app.constants';
let myTestApiModule = [];
if (!environment.production) {
   myTestApiModule.push(InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemDataService, 
   { delay: 500 })
   );
}

imports: [
   CommonModule,
   SharedModule,
   ...myTestApiModule,
],
```

Comment: What is `{ delay: 500 }` for?

Comment: It's a delay for call api. For example, i do http.get(...), and i will get result after a pause in 500ms. Just artificial delay for emulation a real server or bad network, and test behavior of your async code.